# Как с помощью Jquery удалить или изменить другой JS код

Tags: jquery

Подскажите как с помощью  Jquery удалить на странице код, в теге `<script>`. Кодов на странице много он идет  вперемешку с HTML, нужно удалить четкий кусок.

Возможно ли из этого кода взять некоторые переменные?

Comment: 1. Зачем? 2. Не получится. После загрузки JavaScript отправляется в автономное плавание отдельно от тега `<script>`. Загруженный тег можно даже удалить